# Maximum number of Linux VPN Client connections?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn

Just quick question, is it possible to have more than 1 VPN client connection at the same time? If it is yes, is there any references to do this.

Currently, I'm using Ubuntu as my Operating System.

Answer (score 2):

Many VPN clients use tun or tap devices, which may be created as needed. Yes, it should be possible in general. But there might be a problem, if your servers assign you more than one IP address in the same netmask, because you won't be able to set appropriate routes.

What client software do you use?

If you are using OpenVPN, the `dev` directive tells the software which device to use. If you just pass `tun` or `tap`, OpenVPN will create a new device as needed. You can also manually create one using the `mktun` directive (see [the manual](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/69-openvpn-21.html) for more information).

Comment: I'm using OpenVPN for the client software